# Discord doesn't show Rich Presence of game run with Flatpak Steam

Tags: steam, linux, discord

So I got a problem:

When I launch a game on Steam, Discord is always able to pick up the game (like Papers, Please or Dude, Stop!), but not any other detail (like the actual/proper name of the game, the game icon, or the time elapsed.

[image: problem]

I say that because if Discord was able to automatically pick up the game I'm playing, that mean the game entry has been created on the Discord Developer Portal, so at least the game icon, the proper name of the game must also show up, but it doesn't.

Now, while Discord is installed natively (installed using the .rpm package), Steam on the other hand is installed using Flatpak. Maybe it's something related to permission (game when launched will be a child process of Steam), but I'm not sure.

So what this problem might be?

Comment: Flatpak applications don't have access to be able to inspect this information; Flatpak applications have intentionally limited access to the underlying system.